# Phonegap geolocation sometimes not working on android

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I have using cordova v3.4.1 to build android and ios app, on ios geolocation function is returning very quickly and works fine always,but on android, sometimes it not working.

The strange thing is after I reboot my android phone,it works fine. In more than a few hours geolocation gets the postion very quickly both in wifi and 3G.

But after serval hours, I open the app again, the geolocation can not work.Sometimes when I  outside, it can get postion with gps satellite,but very slow,often occur timeout error.

I try to remove the app and reinstall it again,but the problem still exist,unless reboot my android phone.when I reboot my android phone,geolocation function is working fine again in future a few hours.

I have test serval android`s phone such as samsang note2, galaxy4 etc, they all have the same problem.when I reboot it, they can get location very quicly.

This problem has troubled me for a long time, so somebody help me?

here is my code below:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
                cb(null,pos)
            },function(errMsg){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){  
            cb(null,pos)
    },function(errMsg){
    cb(errMsg)
    }, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 60*1000*2,
    maximumAge: 1000*60*10
   });
}, {
    enableHighAccuracy: false,
    timeout: 10*1000,
    maximumAge: 1000*60*10
});
```

my config.xml:

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally I have solve the problem,now on my android phone, `getCurrentPosition` function return  location infomation very quickly every time, I never need reboot my phone again!
I'm not sure wether cordova v3.4.1’s geoloation plugin has bugs.

The reason to occur this problem is we always to use browser's `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function to locate the postion,so we must let app use cordova native implementation instead of html5.

Here is the the solution with cordova v3.4.1, hope it can help you,in fact it has resolved my question.

solve step:

1.remove the org.apache.cordova.geolocation

```
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

2.reinstall a new org.apache.cordova.geolocation plugin

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

3.copy the plugin to e:\

enter the plugin folder,such as ‘YOUR_APP_FOLDER\plugins\’

copy the hole `org.apache.cordova.geolocation` to `E:\org.apache.cordova.geolocation`

4.remove the plugin again

```
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

5.edit the `plugin.xml` in `E:\org.apache.cordova.geolocation\plugin.xml`

edit the plugin.xml file like below:

```
... ...
<name>Geolocation</name>
<description>Cordova Geolocation Plugin</description>
<license>Apache 2.0</license>
<keywords>cordova,geolocation</keywords>
<repo>https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git</repo>
<issue>https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/component/12320638</issue>

<!-- android Code Comments
<platform name="android">

    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
        <uses-permissionandroid android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    </config-file>

</platform>
-->

 <!-- amazon-fireos change to android-->
<platform name="android"> 

    <js-module src="www/Coordinates.js" name="Coordinates">
        <clobbers target="Coordinates" />
    </js-module>

    <js-module src="www/PositionError.js" name="PositionError">
        <clobbers target="PositionError" />
    </js-module>

    <js-module src="www/Position.js" name="Position">
        <clobbers target="Position" />
    </js-module>

    <js-module src="www/geolocation.js" name="geolocation">
        <clobbers target="navigator.geolocation" />
    </js-module>

    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="Geolocation">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/amazon/GeoBroker.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/geolocation" />
    <source-file src="src/amazon/GPSListener.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/geolocation" />
    <source-file src="src/amazon/NetworkListener.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/geolocation" />
    <source-file src="src/amazon/CordovaLocationListener.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/geolocation" />

</platform>

<!-- ios -->
<platform name="ios">
... ...
```

6.add plugin again

```
$ cordova plugin add E:\org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

7、run build commond

```
$ cordova build android
```

8.check if it work fine

check `YOUR_APP\plugins\android.json` must include:

```
{
   "xml": "<feature name=\"Geolocation\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker\" /></feature>",
   "count": 1
},
... ...
{
  "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION\" />",
  "count": 4
},
{
   "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION\" />",
    "count": 4
},
{
  "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS\" />",
  "count": 1
 }
```

check `YOUR_APP\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml` must include:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

check `YOUR_APP\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml` must include:

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
```

9.run the app

write the geelocation code to get lat and lng:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
            alert('suc')
            alert(JSON.stringify(pos))
        },function(errMsg){
               alert(JSON.stringify(errMsg))
               navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){  
                 alert('suc')
                 alert(JSON.stringify(pos))
               },function(errMsg){
                 alert(JSON.stringify(errMsg))
               }, {
               enableHighAccuracy: true,
               timeout: 60*1000*2,
               maximumAge: 1000*60*10
               });
          }, {
enableHighAccuracy: false,
timeout: 60*1000,
maximumAge: 1000*60*10
```

});

if your phone support use wifi/3G locate then we will get location immediately,else you will see the `errMsg timeout` and then `geolocation` will use gps to locate postion with native implement.

now we get the lat and lng, and never need reboot the android phone agian,thank goodness.

if you still have the problem,try to install the plugin to clean the webview cache:

https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-cache

Comment: This issue is still alive on PG 3.5 and your solution still works!

Comment: Do we still need to do all of this in PG 5.1.1 ? Most of the time the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() don't work at all on my Android device. Rebooting it doesn't help either.

Comment: Sorry to push up this topic - how do we solve this when doing phonegap build. Will the changes still be working? I am not seeing any difference, hence asking

Comment: `.copy the plugin to e:\` what is `e` here ? i am using ionic

Answer (score 0):

on cordova v5.3.3，you need to do this：

1、cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-geolocation

2、cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation

3、copy your cordova-plugin-geolocation directory in your plguins dir to e:\

4、edit plugin.xml , add this:

```
<js-module src="www/Coordinates.js" name="Coordinates">
    <clobbers target="Coordinates" />
</js-module>

<js-module src="www/PositionError.js" name="PositionError">
    <clobbers target="PositionError" />
</js-module>

<js-module src="www/Position.js" name="Position">
    <clobbers target="Position" />
</js-module>

<js-module src="www/geolocation.js" name="geolocation">
    <clobbers target="navigator.geolocation" />
</js-module>

<config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker"/>
    </feature>
</config-file>

<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
</config-file>
```

5、cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-geolocation

6、cordova plugin add e:\cordova-plugin-geolocation

7、cordova run android
now, I got gps position well. thanks for WuZhonghua.

Comment: I have cordova 5.4.1 on a mac. I have done the changes you described but the onSuccess or onError method are never called when I issue navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError); Any idea ?

Comment: @Luc using this `value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker"` instead of `value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.Geolocation` breaks getCurrentPosition for me as well. did you figure it out?