# PhoneGap/Cordova V3.4.0 - GPS Plugin Not Working Properly- Cache the latest point forever

Tags: caching, cordova, gps, geolocation

I tried and struggled for several days to get the Cordova V3.4, GPS Plugin to work properly.
I see on the internet and also here for a lot of solution and suggestion, but non of them solved this issue.

The issue is occur **only on Phone Gap Apps[with APK Deploy on Device or in Simulator]** (In browser the GPS work fine).

Testing Details:

1. Phone: Nexus 5 And Samsung Galaxi 2.
2. Simulator: Android Regular Simulator And GenyMotion Simulator.
3. Cordova Installation: By CLI

   - I added geolocation plugin by CLI
   - I added Permission to AndroiedManifest:

     ```
     uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" 
     uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
     uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
     uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
     ```
   - in config.xml:
     plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"

ISSUE:

After Clean Reboot:(Without GPS)

1. I enter  my app and I an get error with error code - As expected :)
2. I Enable the GPS, re Enter my App, and see the location of my place - As Expected
3. I Disable the GPS, re Enter  my App, and see other location of my place - As Expected
4. GPS Disable, re enter to my App, and see the **SAME POINT AS BEFORE**(I dont know how but it cache it - I disable the maximumAge option by put it with value 0)
5. GPS Disable, Wireless Disable, 3G Network Disable, I run my App and I get the latest location Same As Point 4. And Now the **same issue happens forever** and i will get the same position till i will turn on my GPS OR I will reboot my device.

P.S: BTW I tried also to work just with HTML5 Geo Location and I get the SAME ISSUE.

My code: (I tried several times but this is the latest that I've tried to use. I try two call to getCurrentPosition because I read that sometimes one call is Not enough :():

```
var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
      };

      function success(pos) {
        var crd = pos.coords;
        var str = 'Your current position is:'+'Latitude : ' + crd.latitude+'Longitude: ' + crd.longitude+'More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.' + ' TimeStap : ' + crd.ti;
        alert(str);
      }

      function error1(err) {
        alert('error 1');
        alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
        var options = {
          enableHighAccuracy: false,
          timeout: 5000,
          maximumAge: 0
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error2, options);
      }

      function error2(err){
        alert('error 2');
        alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
      }

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error1, options);
},
```

Comment: You can find answer to the above question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383750/phonegap-geolocation-sometimes-not-working-on-android Just check it might work in your case.