# Cordova geolocation plugin not working sometimes

Tags: android, cordova, gps, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an app on android that depends heavily on the function of the gps plugin, but after to 2 calls to the gps this stops working. I need to open google maps in order to make the plugin work again.

I'm testing on samsung J1 and huawei G5  (android 5.1.1), cordova v7.0.0 and geolocation plugin version 2.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in another question, check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383750/phonegap-geolocation-sometimes-not-working-on-android#)

thanks to [user2147549](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2147549/user2147549), all credits to him.

this is what work in my case:

on cordova v5.3.3，you need to do this：

1、cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-geolocation

2、cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation

3、copy your cordova-plugin-geolocation directory in your plguins dir to e:\

4、edit plugin.xml , add this:

```
<js-module src="www/Coordinates.js" name="Coordinates">
    <clobbers target="Coordinates" />
</js-module>

<js-module src="www/PositionError.js" name="PositionError">
    <clobbers target="PositionError" />
</js-module>

<js-module src="www/Position.js" name="Position">
    <clobbers target="Position" />
</js-module>

<js-module src="www/geolocation.js" name="geolocation">
    <clobbers target="navigator.geolocation" />
</js-module>

<config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker"/>
    </feature>
</config-file>

<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
</config-file>
```

5、cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-geolocation

6、cordova plugin add e:\cordova-plugin-geolocation

7、cordova run android now, I got gps position well. thanks for WuZhonghua.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this problem can be solved by using an older version of the plugin.

In my case I only need the cordova app to work on android so thats no a problem.

you need to add gps plugin to your proyect like this:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation@0.3.6
```